# The max function with absolute value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is this function the max of a and b?

$ f(a,b) = \cfrac{a+b+\lvert a-b \rvert}{2}$

Edit: copied down the description for the function wrong and made myself even more confused. However, why is this the max function? I have an idea but would like someone else's take/explanation.

Comment: It isn't. That's $\max\{a,b\}$.

Comment: This function is the $\max(a,b)$.

Answer (score 2):

If, $a\ge b$, then $|a-b|=a-b$, that is the difference of $b$ from $a$ is positive. Hence, $b+|a-b|=a$ and $a+(b+|a-b|)=2a$.

Now, if we have $b>a$, $|a-b|=b-a$, and we getting, $a+b+|a-b|=a+b+(b-a)=2b$.

Similarly, you can write $$\text{min}\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$$

---

Think visually by taking a stick of length $a$ and another stick of length $b$. The modulus of difference $|a-b|$ is always the difference of length between two stick. Now, if you add $|a-b|$ amount of stick to the smaller one(no need to know the length, just smaller one visually) then, you will get two stick with length of longest one.

Comment: The formulas also apply when $a = b$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you,  edited.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\max(a,b)+\min(a,b)&=a+b\\
\max(a,b)-\min(a,b)&=|a-b|
\end{align}
$$
so $2\max(a,b)=a+b+|a-b|$ as desired.